# How to get microsoft access sql to join to the same table twice with null ID's possible occasionally?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I can get this to work, meaning a successful query:

```
Me.Listbox.RowSource = 
    "SELECT A.ID, C1.Company, A.[Job Title] 
    FROM Applied AS A 
    LEFT JOIN Company AS C1 ON A.Site  = C1.ID 
    ORDER BY A.ID DESC;"
```

However, this gives me an empty query result:

```
Me.Listbox.RowSource = 
    "SELECT A.ID, C1.Company, A.[Job Title], C2.Company 
    FROM Applied AS A 
    LEFT JOIN Company AS C1 ON A.Site  = C1.ID 
    LEFT JOIN Company AS C2 ON A.Agent = C2.ID 
    ORDER BY A.ID DESC;"
```

Any Idea's what's wrong with this?

I'm using Microsoft Access 2013 and VBA script. My Applied table has two integer fields (`Site` and `Agent`) that point to different primary keys in my `Company` table.  Both `Site` and `Agent` can have null values in an Apply Record, however `Site` is almost always filled in and `Agent` I only use occasionally to point to a company record. I thought about structuring it like an inventory application where you can have more than one company. I will never have more than two of these companies to keep track of; I just want their information pulled from the same companies database.

Comment: Is there any way that you could post some sample data from each of the two tables as well as what you would expect the query to return, given the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

This is your second query:

```
SELECT A.ID, C1.Company, A.[Job Title], C2.Company
FROM Applied AS A LEFT JOIN
     Company AS C1
     ON A.Site  = C1.ID LEFT JOIN
     Company AS C2 ON A.Agent = C2.ID
ORDER BY A.ID DESC;
```

It is not valid syntax for MS Access.  You should check for errors.

MS Access (rather pathetically) requires parentheses around joins:

```
SELECT A.ID, C1.Company, A.[Job Title], C2.Company
FROM (Applied AS A LEFT JOIN
      Company AS C1
      ON A.Site  = C1.ID
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Company AS C2 ON A.Agent = C2.ID
ORDER BY A.ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the second SQL in a regular query. Access normally wants parentheses when you have more than one JOIN in a query, and should complain. Actually I'm surprised it doesn't complain when it loads the second listbox.

If that's the problem, simply do

```sql
SELECT A.ID, C1.Company, A.[Job Title], C2.Company 
FROM (Applied AS A LEFT JOIN Company AS C1 ON A.Site  = C1.ID)
LEFT JOIN Company AS C2 ON A.Agent = C2.ID 
ORDER BY A.ID DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Except now the Select of C2.Company which is a string is showing up as A.Agent Integer in the Query.  Any Ideas on how to fix that one?    (Whoops... I just refreshed the form and now that problem is fixed as well)   Thanks again for your help!